# vba loop excel offset

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through values and assign a value to another cell with an offset but I get a #VALUE error this is a piece of what I'm doing I put the look.value > to make sure I was looping properly the look.offset(4.0).Value is where the problem is coming from I am fairly certain

```
Public Function TotalCharge(cellToCheck As Range) As Double
'Enter range to check
    Dim total As Double
    Dim look As Range
    total = 0
    For Each look In cellToCheck
        If look.Value > 3 Then
            total = total + look.Value
            look.Offset(4,0).Value = "TEST"
        End If

    Next look

    TotalCharge = total

End Function
```

Comment: It won't work if you are calling from a worksheet as a UDF can only put a value in the cell in which it is placed. You can do this with native functions though.